# Проверка попадания точки в GraphicsPath

Tags: c#, .net

Был создан полигон, состоящий из трёх точек и одна независимая точка:

```
GraphicsPath gps = new GraphicsPath(); gps.AddPolygon(new PointF[] {new PointF(0, 6), new PointF(0, 13), new PointF(1.66667, 13)});
PointF p0 = new PointF(0, 3);
```

Требуется проверить, есть ли точка в данном пути. Как делаю:

```
if (gps.IsOutlineVisible(p0, new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 1)) || gps.IsVisible(p0))
{
    // etc
}
```

Однако, проверка выполняется! Почему это происходит, ведь 0;3 явно вне полигона. Спасибо.

Comment: Почему это явно вне полигона? Она на одной из сторон полигона.

Comment: @tym32167 простите, не понимаю. Как? Могу нарисовать даже

Comment: Хм, это походу я затупил, нарисовал и тоже не сошлось :)

Comment: @tym32167 поэтому я и задал вопрос:) Фантастика какая-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое возможно, если используется [MiterLimit](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pen.miterlimit?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Pen_MiterLimit) по умолчанию 10 (судя по созданию пера по месту использования- это так), что приводит к длинному хвосту (Cap) на месте сочленения двух сторон под очень острым углом.

Однако, если перо центрировано на линии, то до точки 3 хвост не достанет (точка D у меня чуть ближе, чем нужно, чтобы обеспечить расстояние 0.5 между параллельными прямыми), только до 4, а вот если оно снаружи, то и до 2 дотянется (прямая через точку E). Я не исключаю, что перо с шириной 1 рисуется снаружи базовой линии, хотя в описании [Alignment](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pen.alignment?view=netframework-4.7.2) этого явно не сказано, но вот в простом GDI есть тонкости с положением перьев c чётной, нечётной и единичной шириной. Вполне вероятно также, что "под капотом" выполняется `Widen` полигона с шириной пера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно говоря, надо посмотреть, как оно рисуется. На таком мелком ничего не увидишь, а вот всё в 10 раз больше и сдвинуто на 100 вправо:

```
  GraphicsPath gps = new GraphicsPath();
 gps.AddPolygon(new PointF[] { new PointF(100, 60), 
                               new PointF(100, 130), 
                               new PointF(116.6667f, 130) });
    Pen pe = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10);
    e.Graphics.DrawPath(pe, gps);
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 0, 30, 200, 30);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 100, 0, 100, 300);
```

Как видим, треугольник пересекает линию `y=30`, но точку (100, 30) не задевает (и `IsOutlineVisible` не срабатывает) - но как оно будет для единичной ширины - MS его знает. Видимо, даже единичный пиксел перекрывает ту точку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать в данном случае? Использовать [point in polygon](https://wrf.ecse.rpi.edu//Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html) алгоритм

Comment: Спасибо большое за объяснение. Да, я уже хотел реализовывать алгоритм..Только я взял на основе интегралов. Ещё раз спасибо!